# Getting the list of classes in current project/war

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I've got a problem. When I trying to get the list of packages, by invoking `Package.getPackages()`, I'm receiving the list of loaded classes by `ClassLoader`. But some classes did not loaded and their packages are not in the `Classloader` cache.

How can I get the full list of classes in my project? My target is to find classes and methods with exact annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Stripes web framework](http://www.stripesframework.org/) already has a utility class to do just this - [ResolverUtil](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/util/ResolverUtil.html).

Stripes is under the [Apache license](http://apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt), so download it and go!